# How to commit to 2 svn repository in eclipse

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, commit

I have a project in a SVN repository. I have 2 projects in Eclipse: one is for branch and the other is for trunk. Currently I am working in the SVN branch. Whenever I need to commit something to the repository, I commit it to the branch and then copy/paste in the trunk source files and commit to trunk. Is there any way I can commit to 2 repository in a single operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can commit to two separate repository locations in eclipse at the same time as long as both locations are under the same project.

However, for what you are asking, this still wouldn't work for you.  What you really should be doing is making your commits to the branch.  Once you are good with your changes to the branch, then use the merge tools located under the `Team` context menu and merge the changes from the branch project to your trunk project.

This will save you lots of trouble of manually having to merge changes from the repository's copy of branch to the trunk project in eclipse.  Once the merge is done, then commit the changes from the branch to the repository's copy of trunk.

Here are some links with examples of how and when to do this:

http://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Subversion+Branching+and+Merging+Techniques
http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2010/03/simple-subversion-branching-and-merging

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I think there is no way to commit to both repository in single click. For that i need to write a different eclipse plugin. By the time i follow above suggestions.

Comment: @dmay - if you've written that eclipse plugin, please let us know.

Comment: @jgifford25 could you provide steps supporting your first statement that `you can commit to 2 separate repository locations in eclipse at the same time`. I'm struggling with how to do that as well. Both locations are under the same project. So I want to select my file or files in eclipse and under the team right click menu I want to commit those files to both locations. I don't see any option that would do that. Could you provide those steps?

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress  : I didn't write any plugin for this feature.